# The constructor __is undefined in Processing

Tags: java

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[1000];    
int totalShapes=0;    


void setup() {    
size(800,800);    
smooth();

for (int i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++ ) {
int r = int(random(2));

if (r == 0) {
  shapes[i] = new Circle(random(width),-1,random(30,80),color(243,240,245),random(0.001,0.5));
} else {
  shapes[i] = new Square(random(width),-1,random(20,70),color(255,240,245),random(0.01,1));}}}

void draw() {    
background(255);    

shapes[totalShapes]=new Shape();
totalShapes++;

if (totalShapes>=shapes.length){
totalShapes=0;}


for (int i = 0; i < totalShapes; i++ ) {
shapes[i].fall();
shapes[i].display();}



class Circle extends Shape {


Circle(float x_, int y_, float r_,int c_,float speed_) {
super(x_,y_,r_,c_,speed_); }


void fall() {
super.fall();
x+=random(0.001,0.5);
r += random(0.001,0.5); 
r = constrain(r,0,100);}


void display() {
ellipseMode(CENTER);
fill(c);
noStroke();
ellipse(x,y,r,r);}}




class Shape {
float x;
int y;
float r;
int c;
float speed;    

Shape(float x_, int y_, float r_,int c_,float speed_) {  //The constructor Shape()is undefined 
x =x_;
y =y_;
r =r_;
c= c_;}    

void fall() {

y +=speed;}    


void display() { }}




class Square extends Shape {

Square(float x_, int y_, float r_,int c_,float speed_) {

super(x_,y_,r_,c_,speed_); }

void fall() {
super.fall();}    


void display() {
rectMode(CENTER);
fill(c);
noStroke();
rect(x,y,r,r);}}
```

The constructor Shape() is undefined

Thank u very much!!!

(this are detailsthis are detailsthis are details)
(this are detailsthis are detailsthis are details)
(this are detailsthis are detailsthis are details)
(this are detailsthis are detailsthis are details)

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. Your post is *really* hard to read at the moment... it doesn't help that you've started off with code completely outside a class, and posted nearly 100 lines of code, most of which is irrelevant. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Also.. don't just copy and paste 'this are details'.

Comment: If you format and indent your code properly you will notice that the `draw` method misses a closing curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a custom constructor (a constructor with parameters) for a class, you need to add the default constructor as well. But if you don't any custom constructors, the compiler implicitly add default constructor for the class.

please add `Shape()` inside the Shape class as the default constructor.